# Remove an item from array

Tags: php

I am creating a webshop with PHP and use sessions to save temp items.

```
<form method="post" action="basket.php">
  <table border="1" style="width:400px;">
    <tr>
      <td style="width:35%;">Product</td>
      <td style="width:30%;">Aantal</td>
      <td style="width:25%;">Totale prijs</td>
      <td style="width:10%;"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['basket']); $i++) {    
      $id     = $_SESSION['basket'][$i]['itemId'];
      $number = $_SESSION['basket'][$i]['number'];

      $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = "' . $id . '"');
      $row    = $result->fetch_assoc();

      $total = $number * $row['price'];
      ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="view_item.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <?php echo $row['name']; ?>    
        </a>
      </td>
      <td><?php echo $number; ?></td>
      <td>&euro; <?php echo $total; ?></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="removeItem[]" value="Verwijder" /></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['removeItem'])) {
      unset($_SESSION['basket'][$i]);
    }

    $_SESSION['basket'] = array_values($_SESSION['basket']);
  }
  ?>
  </table>
</form>
```

When i set 3 items into the session.

```
Array
(
  [basket] => Array
    (
      [0] => Array
        (
          [itemId] => 1
          [number] => 1
          [timestamp] => 1380722942
        )
      [1] => Array
        (
          [itemId] => 1
          [number] => 1
          [timestamp] => 1380722944
        )
      [2] => Array
        (
          [itemId] => 1
          [number] => 1
          [timestamp] => 1380722945
        )
    )
)
```

And remove the second item, it removes the last item also..

What goes wrong?

Can somebody help me?

Comment: note that second item is item #1. Maybe you're removing 2nd item (#2) which is actually 3rd?

Comment: Consider paring down your code to the essential question. That is a lot of code to ask a simple question.

Comment: What code are you using to remove it?

Comment: if (isset($_POST['removeItem'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['basket'][$i]);
    }

Answer (score 1):

You are unsetting the SESSION variable for `basket` inside the `for` loop.  So if the user tries to remove the 2nd item, the `for` loop will continue and all items after that will also be unset.

You should exit the `for` loop after unsetting the correct item

```
if (isset($_POST['removeItem'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['basket'][$i]);
    break;
}
```

You would then also want to move the last line,

`$_SESSION['basket'] = array_values($_SESSION['basket']);`,

outside of the `for` loop so that it gets executed.

**EDIT**

After closer inspection I'm not sure why you are unsetting the SESSION variable *inside* the `for` loop, but I think you need to refactor your code.  Breaking out of the `for` loop would solve your issue with multiple items being removed but would also cause your table to be incomplete (no items in the `basket` after the one you remove would get displayed).  You should handle the removal of an item in a separate place than the creation of the table.  I would move unsetting the SESSION variable for the item you want to remove to the action you call when this form is submitted.

Comment: @Yooouuri If this solved your issue please accept it as the answer so that it is known your issue has been fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove like this.

```
array_splice($_SESSION['basket'], $i, 1);
```

Comment: If the POST removeItem is in the for loop. It always take the first button. So i need to fix that!